# How much free (ie, fermentable) suger is contained in canned fruit puree and how does this affect gravity?

Tags: secondary-fermentation, fruit, specific-gravity

Going to add one can (49oz) of Vintners Harvest Peach Puree to secondary and curious if/how much this will raise gravity.  The nutritional label states the can contains 190 grams of sugar, but not sure how much of this is accessible to the yeast.  Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing how its puree >90% of it will be accessible to the yeast. Whether it all can be fermentable is a different question due to yeast health and the types of sugar (mostly fructose likely) in the fruit/puree.

As for the change in gravity its not going to be significant.
1 lb of table sugar in one gallon would be ~1.046SG
190grams is about 42% of a pound.
So 190grams in 1 gallon would be ~1.019SG
If you are putting that 190grams in a 5 gallon batch then its 1.019 a 5th of that.  So closer to an increase of 1.004.  If you beer was originally 1.050, you could calculate your ABV as if it was starting at 1.054.  But that's not totally accurate because you don't know if you are truly going to ferment it all (likely not) and I'm making an assumption and comparing the sugar in the puree to table sugar to come up with an approximate idea.

Someone my challenge my ballpark math but I think for this exercise and the +/- error in making the measurements it works out fine.

Comment: Do you rather mean 0.004 in "So closer to an increase of 1.004"?

Comment: Don't forget that the part of the purée that's not sugar is mostly water which will dilute the beer. Depending on how much is water, you may end up actually lowering the final alcohol percentage.

Comment: Agreed Tobias Patton.  I was trying to illustrate that the addition of the puree will have a negligible change on the gravity, and its not really worth worrying about it.